# Current date in query builder Qgis

Tags: qgis, date, definition-query

I'm trying to put a query on a vectorlayer with the current date.

The following code works, but I want the current date to be dynamic:

```
cast ("Starttijdstip" as character) <  '2018/03/01' AND  '2018/03/01' < cast ("Eindtijdstip" as character)
```

In 'Select by expression' I can use `now()`, is there something similar in the query builder (layer provider feature filter)?

The layer is a json-file that looks like this: {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[105888.024, 194338.859], [105808.912, 194312.488], [105773.752, 194365.23], [105756.171, 194417.971], [105672.664, 194690.468], [105536.415, 195151.955], [105391.377, 195644.208], [105927.58, 194813.532], [105940.766, 194395.996], [105888.024, 194338.859]]],"type":"Polygon","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"}}}, "type":"Feature", "properties":{"....

Comment: If you are referring to the layer provider feature filter / query, the answer depends on the layer provider, i.e. whether it is a PostGIS layer, Shapefile, or something else.

Comment: Yes, i'm referring to the layer provider feature filter/query. The layer is a json-file with coördinates (the layer has geometry like a shapefile).

Comment: @underdark The json-file looks like this:    {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"geometry":{"coordinates":[[[105888.024, 194338.859], [105808.912, 194312.488], [105773.752, 194365.23], [105756.171, 194417.971], [105672.664, 194690.468], [105536.415, 195151.955], [105391.377, 195644.208], [105927.58, 194813.532], [105940.766, 194395.996], [105888.024, 194338.859]]],"type":"Polygon","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"}}},      "type":"Feature",      "properties":{"....

Comment: Please edit the question text to add this extra information.

Comment: unfortunately, there is no answer - up to this point i've just learned that it depends on the type of the layer provider. but there is no information about in which way ... a comprehensive overview of how to implement the question in shp, gpk and json would be highly appreciated since it is really hard to find any information on the net related to that topic